# I want to calculate the sum of last transaction for A&B

Tags: mysql, sql, redash

Let's say the table looks like this:

| user id | date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2022/11/01 | 5 |
| 456 | 2022/11/02 | 6 |
| 789 | 2022/11/03 | 8 |
| 123 | 2022/11/02 | 9 |
| 456 | 2022/11/04 | 6 |
| 789 | 2022/11/05 | 8 |

I want to calculate the sum of the very last transaction (only one for each user) for A & B  FYI I'm using redash and I'm a beginner not sure what other info would you need, I tried MAX but was not sure how to apply it on more than one specific user.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: tried MAX but not sure how to apply it on multiple users

Comment: OK. It's best if you can edit your question with a) what you've tried and b) a definition of what "sum of last transaction" means. For example, do you mean the value from the most recent date for each user?

Comment: yes I mean to extract the very last dated transaction (only one ) for every user and sum it can you advise the right way to say that 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the sum of Amount where user is A or B and date is the most recent date for each user

```
 SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS total
 FROM (
   SELECT AMOUNT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY USERID ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS RN
   FROM tableyoudidnotname
   WHERE userid in ('A','B')
 ) X
 WHERE X.RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, where we first calculate the maximum date by user in a common-table expression, then join that result-set to the table to sum the associated values.

```
WITH dat
AS
(
SELECT user_id, MAX(date) AS max_date
FROM credit.card
WHERE user_id IN ('A','B','ETC')
GROUP BY user_id
)
SELECT SUM(value) AS sum_on_max_dates
FROM credit.card t
INNER JOIN dat d ON t.user_id = d.user_id AND t.date = m.max_date;
```

Comment: this will get me all users not only A and B right ?

Comment: Yes. But never just use code from the internet. Always test and make sure you understand :)

Comment: Sure I will next thing in the morning but can you clarify where did we specify the users where I can modify and add my actual users and sorry for the headache

Comment: I assume your users are in the user_id column in a table called "table". You will most likely have to change the table name to your actual table name.

Comment: table is called credit.card and I dont want all the users in the column only 10 specific ones

Comment: I have edited my answer. You should put your list of users inside the parentheses in the WHERE clause.

Comment: got this line 4:23: IN value and list items must be the same type or coercible to a common type. Cannot find common type between bigint and varchar(8), all types (without duplicates): [bigint, varchar(8), varchar(7), varchar(6)]

Comment: If the user ID is a text field, they must be wrapped in single-quotes. If the user ID is a number, they don't need the single-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, Used join with the subquery I mention below.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(t1.amount) AS count
FROM
transaction t1
    JOIN
(SELECT 
    user_id, MAX(date) AS max_date
FROM
    transaction
WHERE
    user_id IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY user_id) t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
    AND t2.max_date = t1.date;
```